# There's still remain anyway to surf 100% anonymously on internet using a computer?

Tags: anonymity, internet

There's still a way to be 100% anonymous on internet using a computer?
I know that using a prepaid SIM card you can surf 100% anonymously, as far as your phone hasn't been bought with a credit card that contains your information.

But..what about using a laptop or a desktop computer?

What do you guys think about Whonix project? Can I be 100% anonymous using it?

Comment: Get a fake mustache and glasses combo and head to your local library.

Answer (score -2):

**It is impossible to use the internet without leaking any kind of data.** This is true even when you hijack someone else's wifi or use a stolen SIM card and sit behind 7 proxies. You always leave traces and you can be tracked sooner or later.

The effort to remain anonymous increases **exponentially** with the level of anonymity up to a point where you can only use the internet passively.

There are various kinds of operating systems like Tails, Whonix, etc utilizing Tor and alike to maintain a big amount of anonymity, but even Tor has been convincingly proven to be not completely anonymous after all.

The tinfoil hat paranoia about privacy is **vastly** overrated.

Comment: "Tor has been convincingly proven to be not completely anonymous after all" please provide sources if you are going to make such statements.

Comment: I'm not going to list them all, but Operation Onymous, Magneto, AS or exit node eavesdropping, IPs can be leaked by DHT, and so on. It requires more effort, but you are definitely not anonymous in Tor given an attacker has both resources and knowledge. Tor has always said that this type of attack could be possible, but that the incidence of false positives make it infeasible for law enforcement to use. In other words, Tor is preaching safety in numbers and the takedowns of quite a few darknet sites have proven that it's possible to identify users.